# Not writing to file, but no errors PHP

Tags: php, file

I am trying to write data from form inputs to a text file using PHP. The file seems to load correctly, but does not write the data.

I have echoed the input values directly before trying to write to ensure they are not empty.

The text file is in the same directory as the php file.

I orginally got the error "Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource" but corrected that by adjusting the permissions on the text file.

My current code

```
$fp = fopen('sidebar_subscribers.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $name."\t".$email."\t".$leader."\t".$industry."\t".$country."\t".$zip."\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Why are the values not getting written to the text document?

Is there anything on the server that php needs to be set up for that I should check?

This is being used on a WordPress blog.

Thanks!

****** Issue is now resolved. The file was getting created and written in the wrong location. Thanks for all your help and suggestions. *******

Comment: try: ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); somewhere in the beginning and see if there any errors

Comment: No error returned with "ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written works for me; I'd suggest adding the following to determine where the error is happening:

```
<?php    
  $fp = fopen('sidebar_subscribers.txt', 'a') or die('fopen failed');

  fwrite($fp, "$name\t$email\t$leader\t$industry\t$country\t$zip\r\n") or die('fwrite failed');
?>
```

The original error about an invalid stream resource was a result of not checking your return values, which the "or die()" essentially does for you.  fopen was failing, and returning false, and you were passing false as the first argument to fwrite.

You can further check for errors by examining the return value of fwrite:

```
<?php

$ret = fwrite($fp, "$name\t$email\t$leader\t$industry\t$country\t$zip\r\n");

if ($ret === false)
  die("Fwrite failed");
echo ("fwrite wrote $ret bytes");
?>
```

Comment: I did the above. No die errors returned, and it echoed that it wrote 50 bytes which seems pretty accurate for the small amount of data written. 

The text file is still blank though

Comment: Try changing the file mode to 'w' instead of 'a', see if anything appears in the file.

Comment: Also, try changing your filename to an absolute path, something like "/home/user/sidebar_subscribers.txt" and see if anything is written.  It might be that you are indeed filling a file up with text, but it's a different file than the one you're checking.

Comment: Meagar you are exactly right. A new file was created in the root directory and was getting written to there. How would I specify absolute path, realpath('http://www.test.com/this/is/my/file/subscribe.txt) ?

Comment: @Joe You only need to specify a path to a file you have write permissions to, starting from "/", the root directory.

Comment: @Meagar, i set the path as "$fp = fopen('/wp-content/themes/sitename/sidebar_subscribers.txt', 'a');" and it is saying the file or directory does not exist. This is a WordPress install, is there anything i need to do different?

Comment: @Joe: Try `$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/sitename/sidebar_subscribers.txt', 'a');`

Answer (score 0):

Try `fflush($fp)` before closing.

Comment: fclose always implicitly flushes the buffer.